# ADC converter simulation

Tags: adc, simulation

I am trying to bulid a ADC converter using a counter, LM324 OpAmp, 4011 7-bit ripple carry binary counter and DAC sub-cicuit.
I can't seem to simulate the circuit proparly as I expect to see an increacing step function while I’m getting the following plot.

The circuit:
[image]

The simulation:
[image]

What I expect to see:
[image]

Comment: The reset fires at the same rate as the clock does (1MHz)?

Comment: sorry wrong picture i chnged the rate, still the same simulation result

Comment: The simulation results still don't look very unexpected to me, given the values. How might you describe the expected waveform? What values would be required to produce such a waveform?

Comment: Also consider using a real comparator, not LM324. It's not apparent whether the V_OH would even be considered logic-high by your simulator.

Comment: I would expect the waveform to increase by one resulotion every clock cycle until it reaches 3.5V and than i'd know i reached my desired voltage. also i was required to use the LM324 ...

Comment: "every clock cycle" and when is that?

Comment: at a frequency of 1MHZ because the clock is set to .5us for both ON/OFF states

Comment: And when does the expected output clock?

Comment: @timWilliams at about 60kHz, sorry i'm being so slow I rally want to understand

Comment: What are the numbers along the bottom of the "expected" figure?

Comment: about 100 ms ... i tried simulating it for this period of time but it was the same

Comment: Look better at what you expect ... You must really "slow down" all your settings ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that a simple DAC with R-2R is "noisy".

Here is what one gets with "any" simulator, which is "obvious" (ripple counter, delays).
For a "clean" output, a "sample and hold" is sometimes useful.

If you try making an ADC with this, some adjustments are necessary (clock speed ... and some others)

[image]

Here is what you get with a synchronous counter at 1 MHz. 10 times faster then before.
More clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LM324 is a *slow* op-amp. For comparator operation, 1kHz would be a good speed to see things clearly. You're running it a couple orders of magnitude too fast. Even your reference plot is scaled in *milliseconds*, while you are going through the entire sequence in a fraction of a millisecond.